# Why DELETE query with yb_hash_code() degrades performance in YugabyteDB?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

For a given below schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS public.item_data
(
    item_id uuid NOT NULL,
    id2 integer NOT NULL,
    create_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    modified_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT item_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id, id2)
);
```

We have 48 tablets in yugabyte setup. So, the first hash range is [0, 1395)

Below are the execution times of DELETE queries:

Query 1 (using `yb_hash_code()`):

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE FROM item_data x WHERE yb_hash_code(x.item_id)>=0 and yb_hash_code(x.item_id)<1395 and x.item_id = any in the arrayOfItemIds - taking 2 seconds of execution time
```

Query 2:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE FROM item_data x WHERE x.item_id = any in the listOfItemIds - taking 2 milli seconds of execution time
```

`DELETE` is a write operation, so, the query plan includes:

1. finding shard for the given WHERE clause.
2. executing query on the shard leader
3. replicate the changes on shard followers
4. respond to client

`yb_hash_code()` in WHERE clause should avoid step 1, Is that correct?

Why Query 2 performs faster than Query 1? despite Query 1 uses yb_hash_code()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, because `item_id` is the primary key, YugabyteDB determines the right tablets so you don’t need to filter with hash code.

But you are right, adding the criteria should not add more work. The execution plan shows. My guess is that you see Rows Removed by Index Recheck with approximately 1/48 of the rows there. This means that when having the predicate on hash_code, the other predicate was not pushed down.

There’s an issue for this: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/12094